# How to run a Playwright file using Python

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I am new to playwright. I am trying to run a Playwright file using Python but cannot open the website successfully. Here is my code:

test.py:

```
def test_has_title(page: Page):
    page.goto("https://playwright.dev/")

    # Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
    expect(page).to_have_title(re.compile("Playwright"))

def test_get_started_link(page: Page):
    page.goto("https://playwright.dev/")

    # Click the get started link.
    page.get_by_role("link", name="Get started").click()

    # Expects page to have a heading with the name of Installation.
    expect(page.get_by_role("heading", name="Installation")).to_be_visible()
```

then I run the command: `purest` and got the result:

```
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.9, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/congwang/Downloads/xxxxxx
plugins: anyio-3.5.0
collected 0 items
```

Can you please help me to figure it out?

Comment: What's the `purest` command?

Comment: @ggorlen looks like `pytest` with typos isn't it?

Comment: @I.sh Yeah, that would make sense. In that case, https://playwright.dev/python/docs/test-runners and https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-pytest seem like the way to go. Not sure if OP has tried these.

Answer (score 0):

- It would be more helpful if you can share your project directory structure as sometimes `pytest` wont pick up tests due to incorrect structuring of the directories (especially depending on if they are python packages) and sometimes naming of the test files
- Try making your file name as `my_first_test.py` and then run it using `pytest`
- Also like others have said in the comments above please read the basics about playwright and pytest and then follow the docs as well as try our suggestions and let us know if it worked
- Must reads:
- https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro#installing-playwright
- https://playwright.dev/python/docs/test-runners
- https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html#how-to-invoke-pytest